# Size of virtual memory during run time

Tags: linux

I created an application, whose size, when i am checking using `size` is displayed as

```
  admin@pc:~/Desktop$ size u
  text     data     bss     dec     hex  filename  
  1725     552       16    2293     8f5   u
```

when checking using `ps -au`, during run time

```
admin@pc:~/Desktop$ ps -au  
USER    PID    %CPU %MEM  VSZ    RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND  
admin   16730  0.0  0.0   3876   448 pts/2    S+   15:48   0:00 ./u  
admin   16731  0.0  0.0   3876   252 pts/2    S+   15:48   0:00 ./u
```

1. why is it showing different size of virtual memory as we saw using size command. .i.e why 2293 is different from VSZ (3876) as seen by `ps -au`?
2. As size of virtual memory is very less, it can be accumulate in single page frame(RAM/RSS) of 4k byte. It means, whole process can be loaded into single frame as 2293 byte is less than 4096 byte. Then why is RSS 448 and 252 less than 2293 or 3876?

Comment: Use `pmap` or simply `cat /proc/$(pidof ./u)/maps` to understand the virtual address space of your running program `./u` !

Comment: Just a thought, for this question http://unix.stackexchange.com is more appropriate than SO.

Answer (score 3):

> why is it showing different size of virtual memory as we saw using size command. .i.e why 2293 is different from VSZ (3876) as seen by ps -au?

Stack and heap are not stored in the binary, they are created in run-time only. This is why sizes of `text`, `data` and `bss` sections of a binary don't add up to `VSZ`.

> As size of virtual memory is very less, it can be accumulate in single page frame(RAM/RSS) of 4k byte. It means, whole process can be loaded into single frame as 2293 byte is less than 4096 byte. Then why is RSS 448 and 252 less than 2293 or 3876?

`VSZ` is reported in 1024-byte units. In other words `3876` stands for 3969024 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `u` loads some shared libraries. These add to the size. Use `ldd ./u` to see those.

As for VSZ, the value is in 1 KiB (1024 byte) units:

> VSZ       virtual memory size of the process in KiB (1024-byte units).

(source: Ubuntu man page for ps(1)).

The virtual size contains all memory which your process needs, that also includes pages which are reserved for your process but which it doesn't actually use.

RSS is the amount of memory which currently sitting in RAM. Both processes have reserved the same amount of memory virtually but the second process hasn't actually allocated as much memory (using `malloc(3)` or similar library or kernel calls) or it hasn't loaded all shared libraries, yet (they are partly loaded on demand).

Comment: A unix linker does load all shared libraries on start, it rather resolves symbols on demand, see `man ld.so` and `LD_BIND_NOW`. The application can load shared libraries on demand using `dlopen()`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: They add to the output of `size`. You should see the sum of all shared library code in `VSZ` right after the process has started but they will themselves allocate memory as needed plus the individual code pages won't be mapped into the process space (= not in RSS)

Comment: In ./u process program , i have included stdio.h, unistd.h,string.h header files. Does it mean that process will load only library files (whether these are dynamic or static libraries) associated with header files or will it load all the dynamic and static libraries irrespective of included header files?

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer: That depends on your OS and how it does these things. The `ldd` command answers this.

Comment: but ldd will show only shared library (i.e dynamic library). but what about static library?

Comment: static libraries are, as the name suggests, part of the executable. `size` will include those.

Comment: Thanks Aaron Digulla and to all other for your guidance.